# toggleClass() is not working as expected on label click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

Alright, I'm working on a solution for custom checkboxes, I nest checkbox inside label and hide it, add some css to labels pseudo elements to display custom checkbox.

Now I want to add class `.checked` to a label on its click so related styles are applied, but for some reason I can't seem to get toggle class working, it simply doesn't add the class (addClass and removeClass) work, but thats a bit of a "dirtier" sollution.

JS

```
$('.label-checkbox ').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

HTML

```
<label class="label-checkbox" for="show-news">show news posts
  <input type="checkbox" name="show-news" id="show-news">
</label>
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hhsxyknf/

Comment: Can you create demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Tushar http://jsfiddle.net/zLs7e8w4/

Comment: See Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hhsxyknf/2/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to bind `click` on `label`, you can just call on change of the `checkbox`.

```js
$('input[name="show-news"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label-checkbox" for="show-news">show news posts
  <input type="checkbox" name="show-news" id="show-news">
</label>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar may be just got lucky this time. :D

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. Will accept answer as soon as I am allowed. for more universal sollution people can also do something like $('.label-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]')

Comment: Added CSS class, so that Demo can be seen more visually

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is right, AFAIK. Check out this, do you want something like this? You may need to consider binding the event with the `change` event of the `<input>` than the `<label>`:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.label-checkbox input').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest(".label-checkbox").toggleClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.checked {font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label-checkbox" for="show-news">show news posts
  <input type="checkbox" name="show-news" id="show-news">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

When label is clicked, you also click the checkbox; thus, you get two clicks and your class toggle goes to checked then immediately removes it.